# How do I create a Timeline Slicer using win32com on Excel

Tags: python, excel, vba, pivot-table, win32com

I have created a Pivot Table and was able to add a Slicer, now I am trying to figure out how to add a Timeline Slicer to the work sheet, but no luck.

I have tried:
`wb.SlicerCaches.Add2(ws_ccpivot.PivotTables("PivotTable2"), "Impact Restore Time").Slicers.Add(SlicerDestination=ws_ccpivot, Name="Impact Restore Time", Caption="Impact Restore Timeline", Top=48.05, Left=496.75, Width=144.0, Height=295.5)`

Which is the closet I have gotten but it seems to be a regular slicer and doesn't let me change it.

Tried this also:
`pt.PivotFields("Impact Restore Time").PivotFilters.Add2(51, None, '10/10/2017')`
But although successful, it is not shown on the screen.

Can anyone show me the steps to add a timeline slicer to a workbook?  I have seen a number of articles on it but they are missing key steps and seem to assume it already exists.

Comment: Without speaking to your particular issue, one approach I use is to record a macro (from the Developer menu) in Excel. Run through what you want to achieve, and then look at the resulting VBA. Once you have the Excel object model doing what you want, it is a relatively simple lift to move it to `win32com` in Python.

Comment: Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+L
'
    Range("A5").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches.Add2(ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2"), _
        "Impact Restore Time", , xlTimeline).Slicers.Add ActiveSheet, , _
        "Impact Restore Time", "Impact Restore Time", 222, 711, 262.5, 108
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Impact Restore Time")).Select
End Sub

Comment: wb.SlicerCaches.Add2(ws_ccpivot.PivotTables("PivotTable2"), "Impact Restore Time", "xx", 2).Slicers.Add(SlicerDestination=ws_ccpivot, Name="Impact Restore Time", Caption="Impact Restore Time", Top=50, Left=496.74, Width=382.5, Height=108)
\n\n
This seems to work.  I do have one more question, is there a way to calculate the top/left/width/height based on the inches?  I know there is a utility for power point that converts inches to pixles, but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: Inches/pixels conversion should be a separate question: it is a whole topic in itself. The win32 api now has additional functions for high DPI monitors, but I am not sure they are exposed in `pywin32` Python package yet?